# Inject a bootstrap-glyphicon into a webpage without overwriting webpage classes

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome-extension

I'm using the chrome.tabs.executeScript() function (and jQuery) to inject a button into a users webpage.  Initially I was using the `<style scoped>` tag to import the entire bootstrap library into the page so that I can use glyphicons in my button:

```
<style>
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

    src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') form      ('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url      ('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
  }
  .glyphicon {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
  .glyphicon-heart:before {
    content: "\e005";
  }
  .glyphicon-heart-empty:before {
    content: "\e143";
  }
</style>
```

I copied this from the bootstrap.css file and had to replace several  `src: url('../fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');` with their actual urls since the relative url no longer makes sense.

the injected button is appearing like this: [image: not working]
while it should look like this:[image: clashing styles]

Answer (score 0):

You have some mistakes in your css defining the font.

Here is the working version;

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

    src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
    src: url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
  }
  .glyphicon {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1;

    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  }
  .glyphicon-heart:before {
    content: "\e005";
  }
  .glyphicon-heart-empty:before {
    content: "\e143";
  }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r4zwc4ce/4/)

Comment: Even after the change you proposed I am still seeing a code and not the actual glyphicon.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware by default, only default script and object resources would be loaded. Obviously the font files are external resources, so you could:

1. Relaxing the default policy by updating `content_security_policy`:

   ```
   "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self' https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com"
   ```
2. (**Recommended**) Make a local copy of bootstrap files and update the font file src with local path.

Comment: While your explanation makes sense, in practice neither of these methods actually works.  Still seeing the glyph code and not the glyph itself

Comment: @GabeO'Leary, if you are using the second way, you should download the entire bootstrap, because the font icon has some dependency on the relative path between css file and font file.